# How to cite a song in a bib file?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

How to site, for instance, the 6th track `Something You Can't Return To` from `Synecdoche, New York (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)`

```
@misc{brion-2008,
  author  = {Jon Brion},
  title   = {Synecdoche, New York (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)},
  year    = {2008},
  publisher = {Lakeshore Records}
}
```

Comment: May be add a `url` as well!

Comment: I struggled with a URL for this question itself. The album doesn't have a Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard data model defines the types `@audio` and `@music`, which would be appropriate here. But the standard styles don't have anything specific set up for these types and will just show the same output as with `@misc`. Some contributed `biblatex` styles, however, do have code set up to deal with `@audio` and `@music`. Luckily for us `biblatex-chicago` is one of these styles.

The examples and explanations in the example file [`dates-test.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/dates-test.bib) suggest that something like the following should work.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@music{synecdoche:omps:something,
  author     = {Jon Brion},
  title      = {Something You Can't Return To},
  date       = 2008,
  bookauthor = {Jon Brion},
  booktitle  = {Synecdoche, New York (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)},
  chapter    = {6},
  publisher  = {Lakeshore Records},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{synecdoche:omps:something}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Brion, Jon. 2008. “Something You Can’t Return To.” Track 6 on Synecdoche, New York (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack). Lakeshore Records.]

Comment: My `biblatex-chicago` version is `2018/01/10 v 3.10 biblatex style`. Could it be the reason I'm getting "Chap." instead of "Track"? [image](https://i.imgur.com/NNebkhK.png)

Comment: @simohamed Possibly. I have the newest, which identifies as `2020/04/20 v 3.14 biblatex style` (on CTAN as v2.0). You can remove the `chapter = {6},`, but of course that removes the track number.